# Proving non-emptiness of intersection of two open balls if distance between their centres is upper bound by sum of their radii

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces

Let $(X,d)$ be a metric space and let $B_1 = B(x_1, \epsilon_1)$ and  $B_2 = B(x_2, \epsilon_2)$ be two open neighbourhoods in X. Let $B=B_1 \cap B_2$.

Suppose $d(x_1,x_2) < \epsilon_1 + \epsilon_2$. Can we show that $B\neq \emptyset$ always holds?

Comment: Consider the discrete metric $d$ and $B_1=B(0,3/4)=\{0\}$, $B_2=B(1,3/4)=\{1\}$. Then $d(0,1)=1<3/4+3/4$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. Just consider the two element set $\{0,1\}\subset \mathbb{R}$ with the induced metric, and consider two balls of radius $\frac{3}{4}$ with centers in $0$ resp $1$. Their intersection will be empty.

Comment: This would hold for finite metric spaces like your example. Does it hold for infinite metric spaces?

Comment: No, take $\mathbb{Z}$ with the induced metric from $\mathbb{R}.$ The same example of $B(0,\frac{3}{4})$ and $B(1,\frac{3}{4})$ shows that your result doesn't hold even for infinite metric spaces.

Answer (score 1):

The other answer and comment both show that the answer to your original question is no.

However, your result is true, for example, if we work with **normed spaces** instead...

Let $(X,\|\cdot\|)$ be a normed vector space.

Let $\lambda=\epsilon_2/(\epsilon_1+\epsilon_2)$ and consider the point
$$y:=\lambda x_1 + (1-\lambda)x_2.$$
Then we have that $y \in B(x_1,\epsilon_1) \cap B(x_2,\epsilon_2);$ indeed, we have:
$$\|y-x_1\| = \|(1-\lambda)(x_2-x_1)\|<(1-\lambda)(\epsilon_1+\epsilon_2)=\epsilon_1$$
$$\|y-x_2\| = \|\lambda(x_1-x_2)\|<\lambda(\epsilon_1+\epsilon_2) = \epsilon_2$$